# Exiting apps when sleeping

Tags: macos, applications, macbook-pro, hibernate

Strange, when I'm leaving my Retina Macbook Pro alone, and it starts going to sleep (despite my setting it to not sleep), it tries to close all the apps that I have open.

Why would it do this and is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have "Log out after 60 minutes of inactivity" selected in the "Advanced…" pane of "Security & Privacy" settings enabled.[image: Advanced]

Comment: Thank you very much :) i will try to check it soon, but yes setting was turn ON, now I turn it OFF, let's seee...)